# Error while installing GIMP

Tags: gimp

I've already tried with 3 or 4 tutorials to install GIMP 2.8 or 2.9. But I always get the same error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.9.5~65-0t4~ppa~00faf17) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.9.5~65-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 1:0.3.6.20) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libmypaint (>= 1.3.0-0t2~ppa) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I use elementaryOS 3.0 Freya. Help

Comment: What did you exactly do based on those 3 or 4 tutorials?

Comment: Could you share the tutorials? If you're using a custom ppa, make sure it's for Ubuntu 16.04 and not 16.10. 
You could also install the somewhat older Gimp version from the AppCenter?

Comment: Tutorial example: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/whats-new-in-gimp-2-8-12-plus-install-ubuntu

Comment: http://www.diolinux.com.br/2016/07/como-instalar-o-gimp-29-no-ubuntu.html. Portuguese example

Comment: This sounds like you need a simple `sudo apt install -f`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't know why you need tutorials - if you needed 4 tutorials and still couldn't install it then probably there's something really stinky.

Generally, the easiest way is to hit `Function Key+T` - you'll get the terminal- then write `sudo apt install gimp`. Now you'll be asked for your password (type it and remember that there are no display of typed letters, even dots). When you are asked to type y or n, hit y and enter.
It should install gimp with all it's features.

If you get an error, please provide error message and what tutorials you've used/what have you installed. Maybe you installed some old packages that are not compatible.

Comment: The error mesage i get after running `sudo apt-get install gimp` is exact the same I posted in my question. :/

Comment: Ok, so try running sudo apt-get -f install And again try installing gimp

Comment: If it doesn't work, try using sudo apt autoclean

Comment: None of these worked :s

Comment: Try sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade and if you get info about held packages try: sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade

Comment: If The output is 0 upgraded then try removing broken packages with sudo apt-get remove --dry-run package-name

Comment: As an aside, I've never heard of the `⌘` key referred to as the 'function' key. To avoid confusion I would maybe call it the 'super' key, as the 'function' key normally refers to the key often found on laptops for accessing secondary functions on the F keys.